# Use a Vagrant machine as SFTP connection in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, vagrant, sftp, netbeans-8

I have a little trouble using NetBeans to work on my Vagrant virtual server. What I tried is to create a new PHP Project on a remote server, then NetBeans ask me for the connection so I created a new connection. For hostname I putted in `127.0.0.1` and as user `vagrant` I linked the private key file (generated by vagrant) and filled in the initial directory.

When I try to connect like this it asks me for the password for user vagrant (which I don't have, since it should provide the private key file...). With Vagrant I would need to connect to port `2222` instead of `22` for ssh connections anyway, so I changed the hostname to `127.0.0.1:2222`. Now I get a `java.net.UnknownHostException: 127.0.0.1:2222`

Therefore the question: Was anyone of you able to connect to a vagrant machine with SFTP using NetBeans? If yes, how?

Note: Not sure if it's important, but I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 machine and my NetBeans version is 8.0.2, I've installed the PHP/Web package.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this was asked a long time ago, but it seems like other people have this issue as well.  This works for me on my Mac:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 2222
Protocol: SFTP
user: vagrant
pass: vagrant
```

You end up in the vagrant home directory `/home/vagrant`.